# Insert post into subsite using code

Tags: multisite

I have a custom post type set up on a subsite in a multisite network which the code is in a plugin to activate it only for the subsite.

I have some code that inserts a post using code but I belive it is trying to insert it into the main site. it is simply a php page with

require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

then some $_POST to grab some data and use that to create a post.
This works fine in a standalone install of WordPress but on the multisite it does not work.
Is there a way to choose the site to add the post to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to switch your context to the subsite in which the posts need to be created. Have a look at the switch_to_blog() and restore_current() functions in wp-includes/ms-blogs.php See http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php.source.html#l437